# How to Junit test that default constructor?

Tags: java

How I can unit this constructor?

```
private Item[] items;

private int currentIndex;



/**
 * Default Constructor
 */
public Inventory() 
{
    this.items = new Item[1];
    this.currentIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have any logic to test.

Comment: Assert getCurrentIndex() == 0. Assert getItems().length == 1. Assert getItems()[0] == null.

Comment: Will not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's standard practice to make non-public test members and fields package private. Like this,

```
Item[] items;
int currentIndex;

public Inventory() 
{
    this.items = new Item[1];
    this.currentIndex = 0;
}
```

Now as long as the unit test is in the same package as the `Inventory` class,

```
public void testCtor() {
 Inventory i = new Inventory();
 assertNotNull(i.items);
 assertEqual(1, i.items.length);
 assertEqual(0, i.currentIndex);
}
```

Comment: Changing productive code for testing purposes is no good practice in my opinion.

Comment: Code has to be written to be testable. If you'd designed the production code to be testable in the first place you wouldn't have this problem. Are you claiming that you think it's wrong to go back and fix broken code?

Comment: That is not what I want to say. When having members that are intended to be private changing this only for Unit Tests is what I don' t like.

Comment: And having private members without access from outside is not broken code imo.

Comment: Do you know what is a package private member? Go look it up, then edit your answer regarding "access from the outside".

Comment: Of course I know what package private visibility is. I meant Access from outside the class.

Comment: Listen, you are almost out of straws to grasp at here to be careful what you post next. So, your claim here is that the field "currentIndex" is supposed to be set to 0, and never change? Or maybe you don't understand what immutable means.

Comment: Hmmmm... Ok. Your point. I'll remove the downvote if possible.